# Cloud-optimized vector format

Tags: vector-tiles, vector-layer, cloud-gis

Currently, [cloud-optimized GeoTIFFs (COGs)](https://www.cogeo.org/) are a great format for storing rasters on the cloud, with the ability to read only the portions that you need (stream) at a given time from a client.

> Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF relies on two complementary pieces of technology.

> The first is the ability of a GeoTIFF to not only store the raw pixels of the image, but to also organize those pixels in particular ways. The second is HTTP GET range requests, that let clients ask for just the portions of a file that they need. Together these enable fully online processing of data by COG-aware clients, as they can stream the right parts of the GeoTIFF as they need it, instead of having to download the whole file.

Is there a similar option for vector data?

Ideally this would be just a file format, and not involving a dedicated server..

I already tried creating vector tile layers using [tippecanoe](https://github.com/felt/tippecanoe/), which is great for visualizing my large vector data in an interactive map (leaflet). Leaflet even allows to display the properties for a single feature. However, what If I want to do some actual geospatial processing with the features?

I don't feel that I get the equivalent "data retrieval" as I do with rasters using COGs.

Note that I can read a vector file from a URL using GeoPandas, e.g.:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
data = gpd.read_file(url_to_geojson)
```

or

```py
data = gpd.read_parquet("gs://bucket/myfile.parquet")
```

For my big file, as GeoJSON it takes about 2 minutes to load, while as parquet it takes 20s, both are reading the entire file.

I would like to only read a portion of the file as needed.

Comment: If your data is big enough for this to matter you should be using an indexed database

Comment: flatgeobuf?  https://github.com/flatgeobuf/flatgeobuf https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/flatgeobuf.html https://cholmes.medium.com/an-overview-of-cloud-native-vector-c223845638e0

Answer (score 1):

That was one of the design goals of lthe FlatGeobuf format https://flatgeobuf.org/. Flatgeobuf supports spatial indexing and therefore reading small rectangular subsets of vector data is fast. Try for example this live demo https://flatgeobuf.org/examples/openlayers/filtered.html.

If your aim is to run attribute queries `"select * from bigdataset where attr1=3"` then FlatGeobuf is not good because it does not support indexes on the attributes.

A blog about cloud-optimized shapefiles may also be interesting reading https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2022/04/coshp.html.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be using Protomaps pmtiles. This vector format is the closest you will get to COG. https://docs.protomaps.com/pmtiles/

- PMTiles is a general format for tiled data addressed by Z/X/Y
  coordinates. This can be cartographic basemap vector tiles, remote
  sensing observations, JPEG images, or more.

  PMTiles readers use HTTP Range Requests to fetch only the relevant
  tile or metadata inside a PMTiles archive on-demand.

https://protomaps.com/faq

- Cloud Optimized GeoTIFFs A Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF (COG) is a raster
  TIFF file with a specific internal organization that enables remote
  reads from cloud storage.

  PMTiles is inspired directly by COG, with a few key differences:

  PMTiles stores arbitrary tiled data, not just TIFF images. COG is
  backwards-compatible with software that can read GeoTIFF. The tiling
  and overview organization of PMTiles is always a powers-of-two
  pyramid, used by Web Mercator Z/X/Y map tiles. PMTiles has very
  concise CDN integration because of its internal design. The
  equivalent for COG is TiTiler. If your workflows already use GeoTIFF,
  COG is the best choice. It also makes sense to use PMTiles for vector
  data in conjunction with COG in the same map application. You can
  think about PMTiles as "COG for vector tiles".
  The arrangement of tiles and directories is designed to minimize the    amount of overhead requests when panning and
  zooming.*